# silent invitations to a google classroom

Tags: google-workspace, google-classroom

We want to invite an entire Gsuite account to a specific Google Classroom without having them accept an invitation.  Basically an auto-enroll that you might see in other Learning Management Systems.  Our end goal is to reduce the steps required to get a staffer to complete an assignment.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this **cannot** be achieved since the users need to accept the invitation/s sent in order to join the class.

According to [this documentation page](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6020297?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

> You have 2 ways to join a class:
>
> - **Join a class with a class code** — If your teacher gives you a class code, use this code to add yourself to the class. Your teacher might give you the code while you’re in class or email it to you.
> - **Accept an invitation from your teacher** — If your teacher sends you an invitation, you’ll see `Join` on the class card on your Classroom homepage.

A possible solution would be to generate a code for the class and share it afterwards.

#### Reference

- [Google Classroom Help](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6020282?hl=en&ref_topic=9049977).